# PHP command script

Tags: php

I had updated the php.exe file from the System Advanced Settings : `F:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.23`

Running php script stored in wamp server folder from command line

php admin/tool/task/cli/inner_task.php shows an error

> Could not open input file: admin/tool/task/cli/inner_task.php

Where admin is the actual php code folder

How a php script is executed from wamp server in command line

Comment: You probably have to use the absolute path, that is what I do.

Comment: Could you guide me: the exact path is F:\wamp64\www\projectnet\admin\tool\task\cli\inner_task.php

Comment: did you try it, you also need to use the `-f` flag, so `php -f  F:\wamp64\www\projectnet\admin\tool\task\cli\inner_task.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`php f:\wamp64\www\projectnet\admin\tool\task\cli\inner_task.php`

or

`php -f f:\wamp64\www\projectnet\admin\tool\task\cli\inner_task.php`
(minus -f parses and excutes the file)

You should note that when you run `php` you might not be running the version you are expecting on the command line unless it's registered in your computer's system variables under the PATH attribute.

To check the version you can run `php -v`

Comment: They said it was `I had updated the php.exe file from the System Advanced Settings : F:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.23` well that's all I'm saying...

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that that's running on the command line - it might just be running as php7.0.23 for the web server and not the cli.

Comment: Where do you think the Environmental variables are?  `System Properties > Advanced` then `Environmental variables`, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use the absolute path and the `-f` flag like this

```
>php -f F:\wamp64\www\projectnet\admin\tool\task\cli\inner_task.php
```

From help

```
>php -h
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
php [options] -S <addr>:<port> [-t docroot]
php [options] -- [args...]
php [options] -a
-a               Run interactively
-c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
-n               No php.ini file will be used
-d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
-e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
-f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
-h               This help
-i               PHP information
-l               Syntax check only (lint)
-m               Show compiled in modules
-r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
-B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
-R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
-F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
-E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
-H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
-S <addr>:<port> Run with built-in web server.
-t <docroot>     Specify document root <docroot> for built-in web server.
-s               Output HTML syntax highlighted source.
-v               Version number
-w               Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.
-z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
               starts with - or script is read from stdin
--ini            Show configuration file names
--rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
--rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
--re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
--rz <name>      Show information about Zend extension <name>.
--ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

Or specifically

```
 -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
```

Comment: Could you tell me f refers to?

Comment: @Saranya Parse and Execute?

Comment: Execute?? what do you mean.  That means Run.  Parse file and run it.  In otherwords, what you want.